# Unsubscribing in Angular NGXS

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, ngxs

I’m new to NGXS in Angular and I have read that you don’t need to unsubscribe when you use the async pipe. However I’m also subscribing from the queryParams and I’m subscribing from the dispatches action. Do I need to unsubscribe from this 2 codes below?

```
this.route.queryParamMap
 .pipe(map(params => params.get('page')))
 .subscribe((page: any) => {
   this.page = page;
   console.log(page);
  });
```

---

```
this.store.dispatch(new AddEmployee(form.value)).subscribe(() => {
 form.reset();
 this.modalReference.close();
```

Comment: not sure about the store's observables, but ActivatedRoute ones are handled by Angular.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription

Short answer:  You don't have to for these two cases since the observables will both complete after firing once.  It's not easy to know when you have to or not in a general sense.  Some prominent developers believe you should never have to unsubscribe.  Others feel you should always unsubscribe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from \`Subscription\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is don't need to unsubscribe from these two set of codes.
Because routes are handled by Angular and second, the store is handled by ngxs. No need to unsubscribe. Unsubscribe only when using rxjs

[GitHub: Does I need to unsubscribe on distaching actions?](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/479)

> amcdnl commented on Jul 3, 2018
>
> Nope. Its handled for you.,

Comment: Do you have a reference that confirms this?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure that NGXS itself takes care of any `complete`'s for us. It's now all basic RxJS standards.

From the [link](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/479#issuecomment-447094744) in @Joseph's answer, @Mark Whitfield states:

> If you subscribe to the observable then you need to make sure that you unsubscribe.

**Sliced data**

Dispatching a store Action without subscribing would be a “cold” observable. **No need to unsubscribe.**

```
this.store.dispatch(new FetchStatuses()); // Cold
```

Async pipes are handled by NGXS and or Angular's Async pipe pattern

```
// controller
@Select(SomeState.scope) scope$!: Observable<any>;

// view
<p-dropdown [options]="scope$ | async" ...
```

However, this dispatch scenario would obviously need to be unsubscribed

```
this.store.dispatch(new AddAnimal(name)) // Hot
   .subscribe(res) => {
     // Hot observable, alive until manually completed
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done pretty simple. You need to describe a `Subject` and call it in `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle. Also you should use `takeUntil` pipe on observable with provided `Subject`.

```
destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.service.observable$.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  ).subscribe();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

It's better to use this method when the observable emits value more than once.

For example if you use `this.router.events.subscribe` it will fire events even if the component has been destroyed unless you use the approach shown above.

Comment: My question is do i need to unsubscribe? Which of the two set of codes do i need to unsubscribe?

Comment: One unneeded unsubscribtion is not that bad as if you didn't. I would unsubscribe in both cases thus you don't loose anything and don't cause any potential memory leaks. In case of working with route it should be always unsubscribed when you destroy the component

Comment: Great answer.  This worked well for me using ngxs when I had too many results due to .actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(SomeAction).subscribe(). This becomes a much more inclusive answer for managing unsubscriptions rather than trying to track each individual subscription.